# Show ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is a $2$-group, where $G$ is given by a particular presentation

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, group-presentation, p-groups

This is **Exercise 5.3.5** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Coperatorname%7BAut%7D(G)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apresentation%2C%20OR%20content%3A2-group%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24y%5E%7B2%5En%7D%24&p=8), it is new to MSE.

The exercise is marked as being referred to later on in the text.

*NB:* I have not used the [combinatorial-group-theory](/questions/tagged/combinatorial-group-theory) tag for a reason. The tools available for presentations in the book so far are very limited.

### The Details:

For a given prime $p$, a *$p$-group* is a group such that the order of every element is a power of $p$.

A *group presentation* $\langle X\mid R\rangle $ is the quotient of the free group $F_X$ generated by the elements of $X$ by the normal subgroup $\langle\langle R\rangle\rangle$ of $F_X$ generated by $R$, where $R$ is a set of words in $X\cup X^{-1}$; such words can be written as $u=v$ for $uv^{-1}$.

The *automorphism group* ${\rm Aut}(G)$ of a group $G$ is the group of all isomorphisms from $G$ to $G$ under function composition.

### The Question:

Paraphrased:

> Prove that ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is a $2$-group, where
>
> $$G\cong\langle x,y\mid x^2, y^{2^n}, y^x=y^{1+2^{n-1}}\rangle.$$

Here $y^x$ is defined to be $x^{-1}yx$.

### Thoughts:

If we kill $y^2$ (that is, take the quotient of $G$ by $\langle\langle y^2\rangle\rangle$), we get

$$\begin{align}
G/\langle\langle y^2\rangle\rangle &\cong \langle x,y\mid x^2, y^2, yx=xy\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2.
\end{align}$$

That's a $2$-group. This doesn't get me anywhere though, especially since ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2)\cong S_3$, which is not a $2$-group.

---

I have experimented in GAP. Here is some of the code I used:

```
RobinsonExerciseGroup:=function(n)
    local F, rels;
    F:=FreeGroup(2);
    rels:=[(F.1)^2, (F.2)^(2^n), (F.1)^(-1)*(F.2)*(F.1)*(F.2)^(-1-(2^(n-1)))];
    return F/rels;
end;
```

I checked the order of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ up to $n=8$, where the calculation got too much for my laptop. They're all powers of two. I checked the structure of the automorphism group up to $n=8$, too, but I didn't spot any pattern.

---

I know that each automorphism $\varphi:G\to G$ is completely determined by its behaviour on $x$ and $y$; that is, if we know $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$, then we know $\varphi(g)$ for all $g\in G$.

---

Please help  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track, so I will make this a sequence of hints rather than a detailed solution.

Let $A = {\rm Aut}(G)$. In fact $Z := \langle y^2 \rangle = Z(G)$, so $A$ must fix the subgroup $Z$, and it makes sense to look at the action of $A$ on $G/Z \cong C_2 \times C_2$, as you are doing.

Now $A$ has a normal subgroup $A_I$ consisting of those automorphisms that induce the identity on $G/Z$, and $A/A_I$ is isomorphic to the induced action of $A$ on $G/Z$. We need to prove that both $A_I$ and $A/A_I$ are $2$-groups.

$A_I$ consists of the so-called central automorphisms. Why don't you have a go at proving that $A_I$ is a $2$-group?

As for $A/A_I$, as you remarked, ${\rm Aut}(G/Z) \cong S_3$. However, an automorphism of order $3$ would induce a $3$-cycle of the cosets $xZ$, $yZ$ and $xyZ$. Try and prove that no automorphism of $G$ can map $x$ to an element of $yZ$.